# Connect Ranorex to test case management software

Tags: automated-tests, ranorex

I'm a test engineer for a software company and we've recently purchased Ranorex (an automated test application) and I'm looking at connecting it to something like QA Complete (test case management software)

Basically I want to run an automated test in Ranorex and for it to automatically mark a matching test case in QA Complete as passed/failed. I know this will obviously involve some coding at the Ranorex end using the commands from the QA Complete API but I can't find anything that even tells me where to start!

Ranorex seems to be very restrictive with 3rd party integration and offers very little help on the subject.

My manager wants a demo of the compatibility before we purchase QA Complete otherwise it won't be of any use to us.

I'm hoping someone on here has some experience with this sort of thing and can point me in the right direction :-)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ranorex library documentation:

http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/html/R_Project_RanorexApi.htm

I don't know QA Complete, but as far as help with ranorex goes, when ranorex runs a test suite it uses the Run method in the TestSuiteRunner class in the Core.Testing Namespace.

This method returns 0 when a test suite is successful, and -1 if it is a failure, I assume this can be used by QA Complete to indicate sucess or failure

Answer (score -2):

Test Collab integrates well with Ranorex.

We've published an extensive guide to [integrate Test Collab with Ranorex for test management](http://testcollab.com/blog/ranorex-integration-test-automation/).

(Disclaimer: I'm co-founder of Test Collab)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please don't post links as answers. If the link changes or the site goes offline, your answer will become useless. Instead, use the info on the website to build your answer and post the link as reference only. And thank you for the disclaimer, by the way. Cheers.